# In html , how to fix script code

Tags: javascript, script#

I have a problem with the scripts  I made an a program to make code in the internet but when i put the script command in the text box and submit it give an erros and I can submit any type of code but script i can't Im using godady hosting can anyone help me ?

i use this to write my code online from anywhere and i submit my code using php the php process it and make a new file with the name you choose when I write any code like `<html> <head></head><body><h1>hi</h1></body></html>` that code don't give any problem but when i put `<html> <head> <script> </script> </head><body><h1>hi</h1></body></html>` that give me that error Not Acceptable An appropriate representation of the requested resource `/code.php` could not be found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: You put a script command in a text box?  What do you mean by that?  You submit it?  To where, from where?  You get errors?  What errors?  You can submit any type of code?  What do you mean by this?  And, what does GoDaddy have to do with anything at all?

Comment: i use this to write my code online from anywhere and i submit my code using php the php process it and make a new file with the name you choose when I write any code like <html> <head></head><body><h1>hi</h1></body></html> that code don't give any problem but when i put <html> <head> <script>  </script> </head><body><h1>hi</h1></body></html> that give me that error    Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /code.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: You should put that information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your note in the comments, your web host is likely running some sort of security extension to help prevent against attacks, such as XSS attacks.  These server security extensions look for likes like `<script>` tags in submitted data, and will block them.  This is good, because if your code is doing what I think it's doing, you're allowing anyone in the world to take over your web hosting account.

You may be able to turn that security off through configuration, or by nicely asking your host to turn it off for you.  Since you're on Go Daddy, you're probably a bit more restricted.  A VPS gives you more control.

Comment: what hosting did you recommend me ?

Comment: @gaith If you go the VPS route, you have thousands of choices.  Pick one that has a price you can afford, with the bandwidth and resources you need.  If you would like, there is a link on my profile to Digital Ocean which provides good pricing with decent resources, and that link gives you $10 off.  But, there are many other choices.  I believe GoDaddy also does VPS now.